# How to express an argument can take one of two values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Why asignment is not accepted?

```
partnerAndDeliveryData2![key1] = {};
```

First parameter of the method `key1`  should be either "partnerData" or "deliveryData". But seems method signator implementation does not limits it, but intialize an array?!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";

export type SetPartnerAndDeliveryDataIn = {
  partnerData?: NameAndAddress;
  deliveryData?: NameAndAddress;
  businessUseApproval?: boolean;
  email?: string;
  error?: string;
};

export type NameAndAddress = {
  name?: string;
  phoneNumber?: string;
  country?: string;
  postalCode?: string;
  city?: string;
  address?: string;
  taxCode?: string;
};

export default function PartnerAndDeliveryForm(props: {}) {

const [partnerAndDeliveryData, setPartnerAndDeliveryData] =
    useState<SetPartnerAndDeliveryDataIn>({
      partnerData: {
        country: "Magyarország",
      },
    });

const setData = (
    key1: ["partnerData", "deliveryData"],
    value: string
  ) => {
    let partnerAndDeliveryData2 = {
      ...partnerAndDeliveryData,
    };
    partnerAndDeliveryData2![key1] = {};
  }
}
```

[minimal reproducible example](https://tsplay.dev/WYvEzw)

Comment: You're indexing with an array instead of a string, right?  Is this just a typo or something?

Comment: Also, the [mre] should be in the question post as plaintext; external links are great as a supplement but are not sufficient by themselves (review the guidelines for [ask] for more info)

Comment: Note that for a code example to be a [mre] you shouldn't have unrelated problems (what is `key2`?) and you should describe in the question what the problem actually is ("Why asignment is not accepted?" is insufficient; the guidelines for what constitutes a [mre] says "Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.")

Comment: You're looking for a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the form `"partnerData" | "deliveryData"`, but instead you were using a [tuple type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) corresponding to an array of length 2.  This still feels like a typo to me or something... or maybe it's an XY problem because your X is "how to express an argument can take one of two values"  and your Y is to use a tuple type. Could you rephrase the question to be about your actual use case and not only about a failed attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `key1` parameter's type to be either the `"partnerData"` or the `"deliveryData"` string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), then you want it to be [the union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those types, which is expressed via the `|` operator:

```
key1: "partnerData" | "deliveryData" // union of string literals
```

Your current code is erroneously using a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), which corresponds to an array of length 2, whose first element is `"partnerData"` and whose second element is `"deliveryData"`.  That's not what you want:

```
key1: ["partnerData", "deliveryData"] // array of length 2
```

If you change `key1` from a tuple to a union, things should start making more sense:

```
partnerAndDeliveryData2[key1] = {}; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSAyjCjEtgGJQoDmISAdvAF84ZKBBBwARFFQYJAbgBQCpAA9IsODACeYJHDpIYABRSxeSKAEFeAEwAiSADbAAbha12mKAJK84AXlwFODgwUxhzKE9GAH4ALjgAORQeaxtLGxtpQkJFEJsnV3dolHiklKQ0jKykHLy4ACMiYHMcgFViSzAwURcURzKGiAhHVF56pBAUYAGEwhgoFs4JqFEoMvnF3mWFAUVlNWh4bV1y1Ntq7MIAoJDeCo2FpfqwAAsIc0T8EAaLR62diE0BB8PwoFp-s9gqEIPN+gBhCAFSHbepoYDaFGAuAoTJXLH1RgqRHIuZPVG7faqdTwApkFD4RzwMigjDAD5wExmCxpBzONzg1jQEAACh6EDAhASOAEAEogtDgbx5nAANphblWWx8orgkrYYjGcKRXmFAUeLwAXQC0JCtAYTCQAB4DEbNab+cUvL4AHwinC2kKhY0WErSwNBuDA0ELLQJCQAWS4WlM0EIAC8AIecCSYCNwAR5yNy-ZAj4qw0lG4iwMAayQWgAjPGNRFQ14JHAAD6SAqevUdotBvqOfBIMkA6Hy-w+25B0bwVsm7Vmr2MABMNwDkZCADp90ueSv+xbGEOQntA4etfZVwON6r603rYEZXI4AB6D9wCC1lBaaEBF2BQgA)

Comment: Possibly what they _actually_ want is "a key to a property with a given type", https://tsplay.dev/WkM7pN. But you're correct that they certainly don't want a tuple type.